# Setting DIV width based on child image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set DIV width based on the child image. This code below works if there is only one DIV. When there are more, it will only use the width of the first child image (first DIV).

```
$('.img_thumb').each(function(){
   $('img').load(function(){
      var img_width = $('.img_thumb img').width();
      $('.img_thumb').css('width', img_width + 'px');
   });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any div by default takes the width of the child elements (img in your case).  Why do you even need to do this?

Comment: @user that's simply not true. The default width for a `<div>` is `auto`, which is roughly `100%`, less any margins.

Comment: @Matt - clarification.. my statement holds true in case of display: inline-block for parent only

Comment: width: -moz-fit-content; is worth noting as a firefox solution. I don't find webkit or trident implementations on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `.load()` callback, use `this` to refer to the specific image of interest. Get rid of the `.each()`.

```
$('img').load(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        img_width = $this.width();
    $this.closest('.img_thumb').css('width', img_width + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @matt-ball, your code example works. Thanks toeveryone who answered to my question.

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 you have a reference to the object `$('.img_thumb img')`:

```
var img_width = $('.img_thumb img').width()
```

Which is always going to point to the first element. You need to use `$(this)` when you're inside the `.each` in order to target the current element:

```
var img_width = $(this).width()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.img_thumb').each(function(){
   var _this = $(this);
   $(this).find('img').load(function(){
      _this.css('width', $(this).width() + 'px');
   });
});
```

Comment: You'd want to provide a context to the `img` selector, otherwise it will bind a `.load()` handler for every image, on every iteration for the `.each()`. Like so: `$('img', this).load(...)` or `$(this).find('img').load(...)`

Comment: Thank you - beat me to it :) Congrats on your 50k by the way.